# How to get the following pattern via regex in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

I am doing some validations in my form using AngularJS. In that there are a few fields where I need to accept only numbers. The range is from a single digit to n digits. I am planning to using regex in `ngPattern` attribute of AngularJS.

I need to accomplish the following things using the regex:

- If it's a single digit, it should not be a 0. Can be anything between 1 to 9.
- If it's a multi digit number, all numbers from 0 to 9 can be used in any position where not all numbers are 0 i.e. the total value of the input should not be 0

I am struggling to find a regex that will accept such pattern. Is it possible to accept such pattern using regex? Earlier I was thinking that at least the last number should be non-zero digit so that entries like 0000 will not be possible and will have to be 000x where x is anything from 1 to 9. But then this logic is flawed as it wont allow people to input values in multiples of 10.

How do I implement this validation?

Comment: Could you show the code that you have already tried?

Comment: @DaanvanHulst, I know this is wrong but this is what I was trying:
`^([1-9]|[0-9]*)$`. This also I have taken from a Stackoverflow answer and modified it a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is the one you're looking for:

```
^[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$
```

It matches on any number that contains at least one non-zero digit.

Comment: Hey worked perfectly. Can you please tell me the difference between your regex and ^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]*)$ ? Both are giving same result. Just want to be sure about validation.

Comment: Your one doesn't match on anything starting with 0. Your one matches on one non-zero digit or any number starting with non-zero. My regex matches on any number that contain at leas one non-zero digit.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Extremely helpful explanation and answer

Answer (score 1):

An even better answer would be:

```
^(([1-9])|(0?([1-9]{1})[0-9]*))$
```

This is essentially the same as above, though it would allow 01 - 09 (and 01[##] ofcourse) as well, depending on your application.